# Insert records into Contact object and they should be inserted as Person Accounts

Tags: lightning-experience

I want to insert records into Contact through Dataloader and they should be inserted as Person Account records instead of Contact records. Is this possible? When I put the RecordTypeID for the new Contact record equal to a Person Account record type, it gives the following error: 'Record Type ID: this ID value isn't valid for the user: 0124v000001ZX33AAG'.

I have a System Admin profile and I have verified that I have the relevant permissions.

I've also looked into the solution of setting isPersonAccount = TRUE but that isn't possible either. Let me know a solution for this. Thanks!

Comment: Person Account is not a Contact, is a combination of Account & Contact. Insert them as Account instead of Contact with that RecordTypeId for the Person Account

Answer (score 0):

You cannot insert to Contact object and create person Account in standard way. You have to insert the data into Account object only with recordtype as person Account.

If you need to create person Account when Contact is inserted you may have to do customisation like using some Flow/Apex Trigger to create the person Account.